# How to interact with Domain in Silverlight and WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight

Currently I'm working on a project which is using **WCF** directly to interact with Service functionality instead of **WCF RIA**. The problem is I create Model for each Entity (in service) inside silverlight client application for validation, That's OK. But I should populate Server Entities with Client Models each time I want to Insert or Update an Entity in database. Is there any way to prevent these extra works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical first version of an MVVM (Silverlight) Client and (WCF) Service has a lot of duplicate types, logic and mapping between types.

This is one of the reasons why WCF RIA Services has been created.

In a first version of an MVVM application the Model and ViewModel will be very similar. When new requirements appear and the Views get more and more functionality added these will diverge and the Model will become very different from the ViewModel.

The Model will be determined by the the service and the ViewModel by the Views. This will cause the mapping to be less and less trivial.

I have used T4 templates to generate ViewModels based on XML definitions. This prevented the need to write the boring, repetitive mapping code.

**EDIT**
See [the MVMMapper project](http://mvmmapper.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex for the generation of ViewModels using T4

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can you explain T4 template in more details. I'm not familiar with these kind of stuffs.

Comment: I added to my answer; I hesitated to link to a project of my own. You can just read the tutorials to see what I have done but to learn T4 you could DO the tutorials/read my T4 code or search elsewhere on the web.